# Show that the null space of the sum of a matrix and the same matrix in another basis is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have a certain $n\times n$ matrix $M$ such that,
$$M = PDP^T$$
with $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with orthogonal columns, $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ diagonal with positive coefficient.  I also know that $n>m$ but $2m>n$. The eigenvalyes of $M$ are the coefficient of $D$ and some $0$'s.
I now considere $M$ in another basis, say $M' = UMU^T$, with $U$ orthogonal and $U \neq I$ and $UMU^T \neq -M$ (in my problem, $U$ is some kind of rotation matrix).

I'm interested in showing that $$\ker (M+M') = 0$$
I could show that $M$ (and so is $M'$) is s symmetric, positive semidefinite and that
$$\ker M = \ker P^T,$$
so, because $P$  has orthogonal columns, $$\dim \ker M = n-m.$$

Because $M$ and $M'$ are symmetric positive semidefinite,
$$\ker (M+M') = \ker M \cap \ker M'$$
Now, i want to conclude that $$\ker (M+M') = 0,$$
because I have $m$ equation for $\ker M$ and $m$ equation for $\ker M'$ so that the linear system $f(x) = 0$ that defines $\ker M \cap \ker M'$   is overdetermined (because $2m>n$) and the only solution is thus $0$.
Is the last argument correct ? I feel like i could write something more "rigorous" but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply isn't true. Note that
\begin{aligned}
\ker(PDP^T+UDU^T)
&=\ker(PDP^T)\cap\ker(UDU^T)\\
&=\operatorname{range}(P)^\perp\cap\operatorname{range}(P)^\perp\\
&=\left(\operatorname{range}(P)+\operatorname{range}(U)\right)^\perp.
\end{aligned}
So, you are asserting that $\operatorname{range}(P)+\operatorname{range}(U)=\mathbb R^n$ whenever $P$ and $U$ have orthogonal columns. But this is clearly false even if the two matrices have different linear spans. E.g. when $D=I_3,\,P=\pmatrix{e_1&e_2&e_3}$ and $U=\pmatrix{e_2&e_3&e_4}\in\mathbb R^{5\times3}$, we have $PDP^T+UDU^T=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,2,1,0)$, which is singular.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you see if we can make this works if $D$ has only simple eigenvalue ?

Comment: @Djekt No. E.g. the counterexample above is still valid if you take $D=diag(1,2,3)$. The value of $D$ does not affect the kernel.

Comment: Yes of course you are right, thank you